# Program or web service to clean a YouTube account to fix "Content ID claims: Not in a good standing"

Tags: video, youtube

Right now my YouTube account has this warning:

> [image: YouTube’s account status]
>
> Content ID claims: Not in a good standing

I have many videos so it takes forever to clean my accounts. Furthermore, YouTube’s policies are pretty involved.

I’m looking for a program or web-service that can clean a YouTube account to fix "Content ID claims: Not in a good standing" (even if it means deleting videos when needed).

And if possible:

- free
- works on Windows 7 if OS-dependent
- minimize the number of removals
- have an option to download the removed videos (otherwise I can just use Google Takeout so I don't mind that much about it)
- list the actions it intends to take before executing them